# how to set visibility to a class with angular.js

Tags: angularjs

using angular.js is there a way to set the visibility of all the elements in the page with a specific class using a single model variable?

the angular equivalent of

```
$(".myClass").hide();
```

thanks,
  Luca

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward way to do that. I believe the "Angular way" would be to use `ng-class` in those elements, and define a separate CSS class that hides the content.

Answer (score 2):

In html code you can use directive

```
<div ng-show="shouldShow"></div>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.shouldShow =  (true or flase)
```

Comment: but that woudn't help with all the element with `myClass`

Comment: this way I have to add the same ng-show="shouldShow" to every element in the page, I would like to avoid this and set the visibility with every element with the class .myClass with a single operation

Comment: I'm afraid there is no other option if you want do that in angular way then add some directive to each element on page. It's can be ng-show, ng-hide, ng-class that is how angularjs working. Or you can use old good jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try **[ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**

Take a look at this.

Here depends upon the Boolean value of `$scope.data` the content will be shown or hidden.
i.e if `$scope.data = true` content will be hidden, and if false content will be shown

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/89/)**

**Html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <div ng-class="{show: data, hide:data}">Content</div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.data = true;// for Hiding
});
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: But this hides the whole `div`, right? The question was about hiding all elements that have a particular CSS class - which might be all around the page.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to add a directive like this.

```
directive('className', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.hide();
      }
    }
});
```

In MarkUp

```
<div class="className">Content</div>
```

Here is an **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tssA5nnU5Z63ClClg1wI?p=preview)**, made for you.

Comment: Please note that I have added jQuery in that script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be useful to you.Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZTXc/1/)

Html

```
<div ng-app=''>
    <div ng-class="selectCss">Content</div>
    <input type="button" ng-model="selectCss" value="show" ng-click="selectCss='show'"> 
    <input type="button" ng-model="selectCss" value="hide" ng-click="selectCss='hide'"/>
</div>
```

Css

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
```